# Disk Image Mounter

Tags: disk-usage, disk-utility

I am on Ubuntu 12.04 and I don't find Disk Image Mounter as an option when I right click on a ISO file. Can any help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

The Gnome Disk Utility is a tool to manage disk drives and media.
You can install inside a terminal with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-disk-utility
```

This should add  'Disk Image Mounter' to the context menu when right-clicking the ISO file.

[image]

Comment: Has worked for me on ubuntu 15.04

Answer (score 1):

In Nautilus right click on a ISO file and the first choice in the context menu is "Open with Archive Mounter".

Comment: yeah, but I am actually interested in Disk Image Mounter as Archive Mounter is just used for display, for doing modifications its not helpful.